# AWS, Codebuild : Push logs as PDF in s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codebuild

We are running Cypress tests from codebuild...and it's working out good. Our team wants to access the build logs, but they are not given access to it. I would like to create a pdf or a document out of the codebuild logs, and push them to S3. I tried the option in codebuild to push logs to s3, but it creates a compressed file, with random name..

Is there any way to create a PDF or a document from codebuild logs and push it to S3 or some way to make it downloadable for easy viewing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

CodeBuild build logs reside in CloudWatch logs in customer account. CloudWatch does not have a native feature that supports exporting logs to PDF format, however the following API's are available for retrieving CloudWatch logs data "GetLogEvents and FilterLogEvents". You can programmatically design a system to retrieve the log data periodically using your own code and the AWS API/CLI and copy the files to your own location and then convert it to the required format.